# How to get new acess token from refres token for google api in postman

Tags: google-api, postman, bad-request

I am trying to get new access token from my refresh token for google drive api. In my google playground it works but when I want to create the same request in postman or my code it doesn't work and I always get error "Invalid grand type". I don't know to find what is problem.

google developers playground
[image]

postman headers and body
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that there is three steps to the Oauth2 dance.

step one is requesting access of the user and getting the authorization code.

> HTTP GET [https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=%7Bclientid%7D.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code)

Note `&response_type=code` tells the server you want an authorization code returned.

2. step two is to exchange that code for an access token and refresh token.

> POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
> code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code

Note the part where it says `&grant_type=authorization_code`.  this tells the server you are giving them an authorization code.

3 the final step is refreshing your access token.

> POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
> client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token

Note `&grant_type=refresh_token` you are telling the server you are sending them a refresh token.

You appear to be sending a refresh token with the wrong grant type.

I have a video on how to set up postman to use google oauth2

- [How to set up Oauth2 in PostMan.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjCauMywU2Q)
- [Google 3 Legged OAuth2 Flow](https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

Note: Due to a recent change with [Making Google OAuth interactions safer by using more secure OAuth flows](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html#dates-oob)  redirect uri of urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob is going to stop working soon.

Comment: @DalmTo  I check your answer now it makes me more sense but I still don't understand how to write request to get response which looks like on my first picture (acess token, scope ... refresh token)

Comment: Part two should give you that response the grant_type=authorization_code exchange. You really should just let postman do it for you.  Check the video.

Comment: The main issue is that you appear to be trying to send them as a json body. they aren't.  look at my examples.  its query string.   Check your first image. look at the content type its application/x-.www-form-urlencoded  your sending Json.

Comment: @DalmTo I check your video  I do first authorisation I save bearer token and then I sent post request with query string according to my result from google dev and then I get response Unauthorized. Why?

Comment: You cant use the tokens you get from Google oauth playground its only used for testing. Those tokens are only good for a few minutes from what i remember.  Create your own client.

Comment: @DalmTo I created my own client in google console and that client I used in google playground

Comment: can you edit your question and show me where you get getting unauthorized? or open a new question as your current question was related to unsupported grant type. which you appear to have come past now if you are getting unauthorized.